# Question about bounded interval $\left[0,0\right]$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying intervals (tangentially, they came up in the awesome book How to Design Programs) and was wondering if the interval $\left[0,0\right]$ had only one element and why.  It makes sense to me that the interval $\left[0,1\right]$ would have infinite real numbers as elements.  And $\left[0,0.1\right]$ would have infinite real elements (and so on...). But $\left[0,0\right]$ seems like it should have only one element in it, but I don't understand how it could be proven.

Sorry if the question is simplistic!

Fond Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[0, 0]$ does indeed have only one element, $0$: this is because, by definition, $[0, 0]=\{x: 0\le x\le 0\}$, and by trichotomy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)) $0$ is the only number satisfying that condition.

---

Interesting aside: although the interval $[0, a]$ approaches $[0, 0]$ as $a$ approaches $0$ (in a certain sense), the cardinality does "jump" - basically, what this means is that cardinality is not a continuous function on the space of sets of real numbers, although this takes a LOT of work to formalize.

The measure of size that *is* continuous(er) is, well, measure - Lebesgue measure, that is, which is roughly speaking a generalization of the length of an interval https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure. On the plus side it has many nice properties, including a kind of continuity; on the downside it is very abstract, and working with it requires serious thought (real analysis). For example, even proving that the measure of $[0, a]$ is $a$ requires some work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Noah! I'll look into Trichotomy.  Is cardinality continuous until a reaches 0?

Comment: Yes, the cardinality of $[0, a]$ will be the same for all $a > 0$, and the only discontinuity is at $a = 0$. It's actually quite common for a property that is true for a sequence is false in the limit - compare something like the truth of the statement "The set of integers between 0 and N is of finite size" and what happens as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

It just comes down to definitions. The definition of $[a,b]$ is 
$$
[a,b] = \{x\in \mathbb{R} | a\leq x \leq b\}$$Thinking about $[0,0]$ makes it clear that $0$ is the only element satisfing $0\leq x \leq 0$. For any two distinct reals, $a < b$, there are infinitely many reals satisfy $a\leq x \leq b$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  So it is a definition. It was just confusing to me that for any number a < b there are infinitely many reals, but it suddenly jumps to 1 when you get a = a.  What's going on there?

Comment: I could probably say something about the finite intersection of open sets is open. While's it's true in terms of mechanics, it isn't very strong intuition. The structure of the real line takes a while really to get used to. I'll keep thinking about how to explain it.